# Tag Groups and search filters

Tags: discussion, feature-request

This is a second revision based on Manishearth's response below.

He pointed out that there is this [feature](http://stackexchange.com/filters/46870/favorite-tags) on the network wide site, to filter out questions based on tag groups.

While I will be very happy to use this feature on the network wide site, I propose that we inherit this feature directly into Physics Stack Exchange.

I see a few advantages if this feature is introduced.

- It will be within the site itself, and users don't have to go anywhere else to access his feature. Its a rather obscure place to look for right now.
- Each set of people with common interests(thus tags) have a place of their own.
- People will be not on be on each others throats for space on the main page. The string theorists for example will not have to bother all about what the homework guys are doing on their side of the digital space.
- It would make the site much easier to use and add a lot of flexibility.
- People interested in serious research, would have a much easier time.

A box on the left(or right) with tag groups that you have created would be an ideal interface. Once you click on a group you will see the usual options(Active, Hot, Week, Month) relevant to the tags you selected. There will be an edit button to make new tag groups and modify or delete existing ones.

Ofcourse this would only work to complement the Main Page, Which in recent times has become rather tedious to browse.

Answer (score 1):

[Here?](http://stackexchange.com/filters/46870/favorite-tags) Note that it's an aggregate of qs from your network-wide favorite tags. Of course, you can create your own filter and copy-paste the list of favorite tags into it.

Comment: Nice, Why not introduce this feature directly into PSE, so that it would be accessible to all users without having to hunt for this page? We can group tags together and filter them as we wish.

Comment: @Prathyush Sure, feel free to propose it (looks like you already have).

Comment: Weird, contains some random tags for me...